# Java MySQL Connects not to other server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to create a sql connection to another server with the default jdbc drivers but the applications connects alwas to the localhost. I've tryed it on tow different machines.

Here is my code

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://yourname.xyz:3306/database?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true", "user", "password");
```

Please help me :)

Regrads

Comment: i use yourname.xyz

Comment: the ip isn't the problem

Comment: what is the problem then?did you get any error?

Comment: In the error message there is the local hostname and not the hostname from my server

Comment: can show us the error please, how we can understand your problem like this?

Comment: Thy JDBC URL doth not contain the correct hostname, port, or database name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your hostname, port, database name and so on and tell us if there's something wrong with it.